# What is the approximate max frequency of the EM radiation emitted from a Raspberry Pi Zero?

Tags: circuit-analysis, rf, integrated-circuit, raspberry-pi, electromagnetism

I would like to know an estimate the maximum frequency range of the EM radiation emitted from a Raspberry Pi Zero computer. I'm working on a radio project and I need to know what frequency ranges are polluted by EMI from the device.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/pi-zero

The Pi Zero device doesn't have any inductors or other intense parts. It's just a couple of resistances, capacitors, oscillators, LEDs and soc chips.
(**I am talking about v1.2 version of the chip here**, since 1.3 and newer ones have bluetooth and wireless built in it, which probably increases it's overally frequency)

The clock rate of the CPU is around 700-800 MHz.

The voltage moves between 5.24-5.26 V DC, at probably less than 10 Hz, also there is about 0.5 mV AC voltage also changing at less than 10 Hz. The current consumption depends on idle or work state,but it's probably changing at less than 100 Hz frequency. Now these measurements were done on the cables, but I assume the frequency is much higher in the CPU, or perhaps other parts of the circuit.

I don't have the tools necessary to measure the frequency of the EM waves emanated from the circuit.

So I would appreciate if somebody can tell me an estimation of what frequencies do these EMI waves propagate?

EDIT: [Here are the schematics of the V1.3 chip](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/RPI-ZERO-V1_3_reduced.pdf)
However as I said I am interested in the 1.2 version, which doesn't have networking components, so ignore the networking and bluetooth chips there I guess.

Comment: DC is certainly less than 10 Hz ;) More to the topic, I don't see how this can be objectively answered without an RF Emission test report, and AFAIK RPi foundation haven't published one.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I found a schematic for 1.3, edited the post, maybe that can help estimate it. I think most of the frequency comes from either the oscillator parts or the CPU chip, so maybe that should be analyzed.

Comment: *The Pi Zero device doesn't have any inductors or other intense parts.* Hmm, **intense parts** And **any** design has an inductor. 1 mm of wire that's 1 nH already. You cannot avoid it. Your question gives me the feeling that you're worrying/concerning yourself too much with something which you do not understand. EMI waves don't just **stop** somewhere, they propagate **infinately**. At some point they're so low in power that you can ignore them. It is unclear what you actually want to achieve with your question. If the answer was -x dBm/m at y m, what would you do with that answer?

Comment: More Hmm, schematics of a chip, nope that's the schematic of a PCB ! Also the fact that you think that it can be estimated from a **schematic** how much a device radiates worries me. If you put it in a metal box (Faraday cage) it cannot radiate, that metal box is never in the schematic.

Comment: @FakeMoustache I see but I still need an approximation, the devices will be close to eachother, 3-4 cm close so the EMI is a problem, and shielding is not an option unfortunately, so I need a frequency range.

Comment: *3-4 cm close so the EMI is a problem* No it is not, now **prove me wrong** by showing facts that **prove** it is a problem.

Comment: According to the schematic, there are no antennas on the RPi, so it won't radiate at all. That's about as much as one could tell about EMI with the schematic alone.

Comment: I would expect to easily measure something in the 5-7GHz range.

Comment: @PlasmaHH do you think that number is influenced by the CPU clock speed, so lowering the CPU clock could lower the EMI frequency?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev the metal on the PCB itself is the unintentional antenna, and I think the transistors inside the CPU could be the unintentional modulators of the EMI. For example the CPU performing tasks and interrupting, that is FM modulation right there I think.

Comment: @AmateurElectronics: It will certainly influence it, but the main factor is likely the sensitivity to the measurement equipment.

Comment: @AmateurElectronics Yes, but the metal on the PCB is not part of the schematic. All lines on the schematic are zero-length and zero-resistance.

Comment: @PlasmaHH of course, but lets say we measure it in a shielded room or anechoic chamber, so the background noise is irrelevant, and we have a very sensitive field probe. How much do you think the radiated frequency will be lowered if I lower the clock rate to 200 Mhz?

Comment: @AmateurElectronics: Besides that the radiated energy does not care if you are in an anechoic chamber or run over by a bus, with a good setup you will be able to measure quite some harmonics, all depending on how fast the edges are, I have seen 23rd harmonics being measured just fine with crips fast edges.

Comment: *I think the transistors inside the CPU could be the unintentional modulators of the EMI* These transistors are smaller than 1um x 1um, not really significant. All experienced designers **know** that the EMI from digital circuits comes from the supply lines and that you need to use supply decoupling caps to keep the **current loop** short to lower EMI emissions. *modulators of the EMI* If you don't understand the principles it might be better to educate yourself on the subject first before making certain statements/assumptions.

Comment: I once measured the 283 rd harmonic of a DCDC converter switching, it was right in the channel we were interested in.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on unbacked claims and OP's misunderstanding. The misunderstanding has been extensively discussed in the comments, but the info given there is not likely to be of future reader's interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fast edges of the MCU chip will convolve with any other impulse response and inject upsetting energy. The CMOS gates and clock drivers and flipflops switch at sub-100picoSecond times; that edge shape, modeled in the sin(x)/x equation, indicates strong energy out past 5GHz, dipping to a null at 10GHz, and rebounding to a peak at 15Ghz, nulling again at 20GHz, on and on.

How does this affect your radio? Ask the question: how will a 2.5 volt edge, transitioning at 100pS rising and 80pS falling, in a 49% duty cycle squarewave, repetition rate of 700MHz, interfere with the antenna/matching/LNA/tuning/mixer of the radio? That 2.5 volts will block (overload) your radio.

With magnetic coupling proportional to dI/dT, the radiated energy will remain constant with frequency, consistent with some comments.

SUMMARY: 
To survive these 2.5 volt silicon events, what to do? Place a solid plane (top layer of PCB) under the MCU. Place a square of copper foil on top, and solder down the corners to the PCB's top plane. Be selective in what PACKAGE you chose for the MCU, if you have a choice. Avoid MCUs that do not keep all VDD/GND pairs *immediately* adjacent. And use dampening resistors in all VDD lines, to ensure filtering even at low (below FerriteBead) frequencies. Program the OutputDrivers to slowest slewrate. Minimize the external Cload on all pins, to minimize the required output current and thus the magnetic field.

DETAILS:
These integrated systems survive because of tiny loop areas, needed on silicon to minimize the energy demanded by the MCU. Large loop areas demand lots of energy and are slow. Thus the people planning MCU floorplans have learned to place the VDD either adjacent to GND or immediately above GND, on the silicon.
The adjacency reduces the inductance, avoiding resonance-generated holes in the SHMOO plots.

This "adjacency" is also used for executing clock-trees, again to reduce the demanded energy, thus small areas, tiny loop areas, tiny radiation loops, are inherent in successful IC development. These tiny loop areas allow the silicon to perform even faster, further speeding the edges and further enhancing the correlation between the edges and any other impulse response.

The prime clock may be 700MHz. But many slower events occur. The 700 MHz cannot come from a 700MHz quartz crystal, instead being scaled by a phase-locked-loop using a 10MHz quartz reference (or whatever your MCU uses). Now we have 10MHz square waves. SPI datalinks, at 50MHz??. Memory fetches at 200MHz?? There are no quiet regions of the spectrum.

To succeed, provide the MCU power totally locally: bypass caps right at the MCU, with some impedance (1 ohm or 3.3 ohm or 10 ohm, or ferrite beads) from the MCU pin to any remote bulk supply. Do not run a trace ---- pure copper metal ---- from the MCU to nearby/remote bypass caps, because that trace becomes a radiating antenna particularly for magnetic fields. Insert a resistor or bead. The copper's skin depth becomes your friend, giving free attenuation in the middle GHz, but not at 700Mhz.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTaUcd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here is the sin(X)/X spectral analysis. Input is 500MHz, 1 volt peak, Tr & Tf = 100picoseconds. Out at 2.4GigaHz, the energy is 6millivolts, or -40 dBm if across 50 Ohms..

[image]